# Need some help with the use of Present Participle

Tags: phrase-usage, present-participles

> He said that marking exams without knowing students' names, and having teachers discuss and review the grades they give with others, would reduce any possible biases caused by personality.

In the paragraph above, they use a present participle with "having teachers" but did not use a present participle with "review the grades". I'm curious as to why? My first assumption is that its because of the Double-ing Constraint but at the beginning of the sentence they used "knowing"?

Comment: It's because the context is a list of ***two*** items - ***marking** [exams]* and ***having** [teachers do things]*. That's to say, it's talking about getting the teachers to ***discuss and review** [the grades they award]*. If we had the continuous form there, it would mean there was a list of ***three*** items - *(1) **marking** exams without knowing students' names, and (2) **having** teachers discuss [unspecified things] and (3) **reviewing** the grades...*

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that "would reduce any possible biases":

1. marking exams without knowing students' names
2. having teachers discuss and review the grades they give with others

That second point uses a parallel structure, so could be understood as

2.a. having teachers discuss the grades they give with others and
2.b. having teachers review the grades they give with others

In both cases the verbs discuss and review are in their base form, because that is used in the "causative" structure "having somebody **do** something"